# Virto Commerce Catalog Export to CSV issue with blob/local storage setting on azure deployment

Tags: virtocommerce

I have an azure deployment, however, when I am exporting to CSV from catalog, it tries to export to the following link:
I have tried to find where the setting is to change this to blob storage but I am a new with the software.  If you change the localhost to the URL of the deployment, it gives a 404 error.  I believe that there is somewhere there is a setting to configure local or blob storage, could you please direct us to where this is? 
By the way, this is from a default azure deployment currently.
Thanks for your help.

Here is a paste of what it returns:

Catalog to csv export

detail
Start export

Start —  4:00:39 AM

End —  4:01:33 AM

Total count

5

Processed count

5

Error count

0

Download Url:http://localhost/admin/Assets/temp/Catalog-newjersey-export.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to switch from local to azure blob storage you can read here [Working with blob storages](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Storage+of+files)

To solve you problem and switch to azure blob storage you need will do next steps:

1. Open you azure storage account (blob) access keys and copy primary connection string
2. Replace in virtocommerce manager web.config exist AssetsConnectionString line to 
   `<add name="AssetsConnectionString" connectionString="provider=AzureBlobStorage; { you storage account connection string }" />`

Comment: I was able to figure this out. Thanks for publishing it for others. I also found that inside of the Web app there's the folder for admin. Inside of it there's a web.config file. You can also add the connection strings there. I mention this because on my deployment until I commented out the local storage storage string it was not using my blob. Thanks.